# Type Erasure - Extending Java Generic Class To Be Non-Generic

Tags: java, generics, extends, type-erasure

If I do this:

```
public class IntegerList extends ArrayList < Integer > { }
```

Am I able to use `IntegerList` normally without worrying about type erasure, meaning I can use and create arrays of them and instantiate them dynamically, and any compliant compiler or IDE will be able to do both compile- and run-time type checking properly?

Comment: While I can't explain technically why, I know the answer is yes, I do such stuff without problems

Comment: Yes, that's absolutely fine (in terms of the language). It's hard to give anything more than that in an answer, to be honest... It's less pleasant in terms of *design* - for example, not every `List<Integer>` is an `IntegerList`, so it's not like you can use them interchangably. But it will *work*.

Comment: Yes, sure. you can. there is no any doubt in it..

Comment: The biggest danger I see here is implementing method overloads... If you implement, say, `.add(int)`, you'll have to make _sure_ that it resorts to `ArrayList`'s `.add()` behind the scenes. IOW: use composition instead!

Comment: I'm just doing this for code readability. I'm doing things like a custom class `PlayerRecord` and then I do `PlayerRecordList extends ArrayList < PlayerRecord >`, and I don't override any methods at all, so it always uses the builtin methods from the ArrayList, and it avoids having the generic in every single declaration, it avoids having an import java.util.ArrayList in every file that uses it, and it lets me instantiate it normally.

Comment: Code readability will suffer here imho. You have more of a design problem. Consider for example that you can make `PlayerRecordList` implement `Iterable<PlayerRecord>` instead, which means you will be able to use it in a foreach loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "instantiate it normally?" I am also baffled by your assertion that you want to "avoid having the generic in every single declaration" and avoid the import. This is not a compelling design rationale; perhaps a bit of extra perspective would be enlightening.

Comment: I can have `public PlayerRecordList PlayerRecords = new PlayerRecordList ( ) ;` and then do `for ( PlayerRecord CurrRecord : PlayerRecords)` just fine without a problem.

And as for readability, it's much easier to understand `HashMap < Integer , PlayerRecordList >` than `HashMap < Integer > , ArrayList < PlayerRecord > >`. If my implementation doesn't care what backend list I'm using, it's silly to have to expose that and add visual complexity.

Comment: If you're trying to get around type erasure you might want to try an approach more like http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `IntegerList` is a *reified type*, which is what I think you're trying to say.

And while we are at it, `ArrayList` is also a reified type, which means you can do the same things with `ArrayList` that you can do with `IntegerList`. (But not with `ArrayList<Integer>`, which is not a reified type.)

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean.  We don't have reified generics in Java, and what you talked is also different from normal understanding of reified generics.  I am interested to know what you are trying to mean, would you mind elaborating a bit more ? :)

Comment: @AdrianShum: Which part do you not understand? When you do `new something[5]`, `something` must be a reified type. When you do `instanceof something`, `something` must be a reified type. So that's exactly what the OP is talking about. A reified type is a type that exists at runtime, i.e. a raw type. Java doesn't have reified generics and this has nothing to do with reified generics. In reified generics, parameterized types are reified types. In Java, they are not.

Comment: oops got what you mean.  I think I have mixed up what you are talking about with reified generics  :P